# Wishing someone good luck in continuing something without yourself without sounding hypocritical or sarcastic

Tags: word-choice

I'm fretting over an email to what was a potential customer. This person announced that he will do the project I pitched on with another company.

I sincerely want to wish the customer good luck with the project, but I can't find the correct phrasing. I'm afraid "Wishing you all the best with the project" might sound like the hypocritical uttering of a sore loser who actually wants the project to go flat on its belly.

Any suggestions as to how one who 'has lost' can still sincerely write he wishes the very best for everyone?

Comment: "Wishing you all the best with the project." sounds just fine to me.

Comment: Laundromat, I wish you all the best with your project of finding the proper wording.

Comment: In the market I worked in as a "freelance solution provider", I don't think it would have been appropriate to convey any such sentiments in the first place. Just thank the "non-customer" for his time and trouble in even allowing you to pitch for the job, and say you're available to be considered for any future requirements.

Comment: 27k views and only 1 upvote? What's wrong with people these days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest that your "Wishing you all the best with the project" line works just fine, unless you and the customer have a history of sarcasm.

Comment: Thanks for "sarcasm", as that was the word I was looking for (edited the title because of it).

Comment: "all the best" can be seen as boilerplatey and insincere....

Answer (score 17):

'I’m really sorry we didn’t get your business this time as I think we could have worked well together. Nevertheless, I do hope your project goes well, and I wish you every success with your chosen partner.'

Comment: I think this works well and feels sincere because it acknowledges the business relationship and the fact that they're going on without you, but it steers clear of sounding like a plea for future work.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like ...

> Mr. Smith,
>
> Thank you for the opportunity to present our services to you.  I appreciate your time and attention, and am grateful to have met you.
>
> I hope we have an opportunity to work together in the future. May your project surpass all of your expectations.  If I can serve you in any way, please, don't hesitate to contact me.
>
> Sincerely

This approach wishes well, shows gratitude, while also putting you in mind for future opportunities.

Comment: "May your project to" ?? I'd edit this, but I'm not sure what you intended here. Also, IMHO exclamation marks are verging on unprofessional.

Comment: I think almost anyone receiving this email in the circumstances OP describes would assume it to be sarcastic, unprofessional, or both.

Comment: @T.E.D, sorry about that.  The 'to' was left over from a previous revision, and my eyes didn't see it until you pointed it out.  I agree the exclamation mark could be construed as unprofessional.

Comment: No big. I didn't downvote, as I figured it was just a editing issue like you said. Just thought I'd point it out, since I couldn't fix it for you myself.